# How much was the population in Satya yuga?

Tags: yuga, krita-yuga

As we know in Satya yuga people lived for about 1 lakh years.

Then how many years they spend in childhood, at what age will they become adults?

At what age usually they were married  ?

Also, what was the population at that time. because as people average age is 1 lakh years, definitely there will be more population than Kali yuga.

Comment: SB Canto 5: During the first yuga, Satya-yuga, people were very pious. Everyone practiced the mystic yoga system for spiritual understanding and realization of God. Because everyone was always absorbed in samādhi, no one was interested in material sense enjoyment. May be they lived in 1 lakh years, but they are more spiritual. I believe very less population (may be 1 million) at that time and no need year count for each stage of life cycle. During Satya yuga the majority of the population is situated in the mode of goodness.

Comment: You may only ask one question at a time. Voting to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Mahayuga, as per Hindu cosmology, began approximately 3.9 million years ago. For the sake of simplicity let's consider the midpoint of Satya Yuga to be around 3 million years ago.

Based on geological evidence, this aligns with the Pliocene epoch of the Cenozoic era. During this period of primates and hominids, it is absurd to think that there were creatures with lifespans of 100K years, engaging in marital unions, and with awareness of piety and spirituality.

It may be possible that long-lived higher order beings existed in a different realm / dimensions but no evidence exists of such a thing on earth.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).